# How to get the google forms responds into mail

Tags: javascript, forms, email, google-sheets, sendmail

I am very new to google scripting and just saw the light (I think).

I have found some code on the Internet (thanks a lot) that I use to trigger an email whenever a form is entered.

I use google form to collect data for my job and when I have been on service visits I have made a form to write various data into. Sometimes the visit is going to be billed and sometimes not. Now to my problem.

With the code I have google sheet well trigger a email when I enter "yes or no to the invoice. google sheet taste the words yes or no" and when I choose "YES" it will trigger the mail and it will sent an email to our economy lady that the customer has to be billed. Great so far

But I do not know how I can get the new entered data (row) in the mail so she does not need to go and have a look in my google sheet (she says that it is hard to navigate all the rows and "it will never going to happen").

So how do I get my newly entered formdata from my (row) into the mail triggered by "yes" (se  the code, the messages it is on danish sorry).

It would be nice if I could determine which cells / information I wanted to bring to my mail, but I'm obviously not smart enough yet ;-)

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get the spreadsheet
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()//Get the active sheet
var cell = ss.getActiveCell().activate();//Get the active cell. 
var triggerCell = cell.getA1Notation();//Get the cells A1 notation.
var triggerCellContent = cell.getValue();//Get the value of that cell. 
var siteUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WKH72ydFh1DcI3IK7P4Ie3rV_wsiX8Xydf9UXMN4BGw/edit?usp=sharing";
var massage = "Dette er en auto genereret mail og der bliver derfor ikke fulgt op på denne besked.</br></br> En kunde skal faktureres, følg linket det er række / celle nr. " + triggerCell + ".";  

  if (triggerCellContent.match("Ja")){
MailApp.sendEmail("fakemail@gmail.com", "Der er en kunde som SKAL faktureres", "Det drejer sig om denne række: " + triggerCell + " Faktureres: " + triggerCellContent + "." + " Link til indhold: " + siteUrl + "." + " Besked: " + massage + ".");
  }

else if (triggerCellContent.match("Nej")){
MailApp.sendEmail("fakemail@gmail.dk; fakemail2@outlook.dk", "Der har været service besøg hos denne kunde", "Denne række er ny: " + triggerCell + " Faktureres: " + triggerCellContent + "." + " Link til indhold: " + siteUrl + ".");
  }

}
```

Here there are links to forms og sheets:

Formular:  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1QPziNq9Y7mAF9lAzAWjtaw0Y2CtvokwQR29Vhnbo1ak/viewform

Google Spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WKH72ydFh1DcI3IK7P4Ie3rV_wsiX8Xydf9UXMN4BGw/edit?usp=sharing

I really hope someone smart person can help me out. And thanks in advance

Tom M Petersen
Denmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get the spreadsheet
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet() //Get the active sheet
```

After the form is submitted, there will be a new row of data in the sheet. So new data is in last row and you can get the data as -

```
var rowData = sheet.getRange( sheet.getLastRow(), 1 or column number to start to get data, 1(don't change), number of columns to take(use sheet.getLastColumn() to grab all columns) ).getValues()[0];
```

rowData is an object and you have to iterate through it to get actual cell values.

```
var text="";
for (i in rowData) {
      text = text + rowData[i] + ", " // format as you need
}
```

text = 'name, email, address....' etc

Then use 'text' in the 'body' to mail.

Comment: Hey Raihan Firoz
Thanks a lot for your quick answer. I am trying to make it work and as a newbie I think it is a bit tricky.